# R.java file is not updating or recovering after clean up

Tags: java, eclipse, r.java-file

I am working with an R.java file that is not getting updated with changes made in an XML file. After I try to clean the project up, the Java file is getting deleted and is not recovering automatically. My package name in the manifest file is correct. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have any additional details, including information on the specific error messaging, the R.java file details, etc. There is not enough information here to provide a good answer without guessing.

Comment: @nathaniel- "brate cannot be resolved or is not a field" this is the error i am getting whr brate is the button variable i am using

Comment: try to delete the R.java file, it should be generated again.